# How to derive sql columns from a XMLcolumn

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a table named dbo.XMLData and one column in the table named XMLValue, a sample row in the table is below( basically its a XML value)

```html
<GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT xmlns="http://xactware.com/generic_roughdraft.xsd" majorVersion="28" minorVersion="300" transactionId="001SPL8">
  <HEADER dateCreated="2015-01-08T20:26:28" />
  <COVERSHEET>
    <ESTIMATE_INFO estimateName="OSCAR_MURPHY" insuredName="Oscar Murphy" priceList="KYLO8X_JAN15" laborEff="Restoration/Service/Remodel" claimNumber="KBR-182015-13:18:46 MST" policyNumber="KBR1467216" typeOfLoss="Collapse" causeOfLoss="collapse" deprMat="1" deprNonMat="1" deprTaxes="1" recipientsXNAddress="XA.ONLINE.TEST" rotationTrade="Re Key\Lock Change" carrierId="2210000" estimateType="Structural" />
    <ADDRESSES>
      <ADDRESS type="Property" street="6467 N 7506 W" city="Louisville" state="KY" zip="40219" primary="1" />
      <ADDRESS type="Home" street="6467 N 7506 W" city="Louisville" state="KY" zip="40219" />
    </ADDRESSES>
    <PHONES>
      <PHONE type="Home" primary="1" phone="(800) 555-5765" />
      <PHONE type="Business" phone="(801) 555-2021" />
      <PHONE type="Cellular" phone="(808) 555-0202" />
    </PHONES>
    <CONTACTS>
      <CONTACT type="ClaimRep" name="John Deeter">
        <ADDRESSES>
          <ADDRESS type="Business" street="100 N 100 E" city="Orem" state="UT" zip="84062" primary="1" />
        </ADDRESSES>
        <PHONES>
          <PHONE primary="1" type="Business" phone="555-555-5554" />
        </PHONES>
      </CONTACT>
      <CONTACT type="Estimator" name="John Deeter">
        <ADDRESSES>
          <ADDRESS type="Business" street="100 N 100 E" city="Orem" state="UT" zip="84062" primary="1" />
        </ADDRESSES>
        <PHONES>
          <PHONE primary="1" type="Business" phone="555-555-5554" />
        </PHONES>
      </CONTACT>
    </CONTACTS>
    <DATES loss="2015-01-07" inspected="2015-01-08T05:00:00Z" completed="2015-01-08T20:26:26Z" received="2015-01-08T20:18:00Z" entered="2015-01-08T20:22:00Z" contacted="2015-01-08T05:00:00Z" />
  </COVERSHEET>
  <COVERAGES>
    <COVERAGE deductible="500" coverageName="Building" coverageType="0" id="1">
      <SUMMARY>
        <TOTALS lineItemTotal="7919.16" subtotal="8060.24" rcv="8060.24" acv="8060.24" deductible="500" fullDeduct="500" netClaim="7560.24">
          <SALES_TAXES>
            <SALES_TAX desc="Material Sales Tax" amount="141.08" taxOP="OPonTax" />
          </SALES_TAXES>
          <SIGNATURE estimator="John Deeter" />
        </TOTALS>
      </SUMMARY>
    </COVERAGE>
  </COVERAGES>
  <RECAP_TAX_OP>
    <TAXES>
      <TAX_DETAIL taxNum="1" rate="6" desc="Material Sales Tax" amount="141.08" />
      <TAX_DETAIL taxNum="2" rate="6" desc="Storage Tax" />
    </TAXES>
    <LINE_ITEMS>
      <TAXES>
        <TAX_AMOUNT taxNum="1" amount="141.08" />
      </TAXES>
    </LINE_ITEMS>
  </RECAP_TAX_OP>
  <LINE_ITEM_DETAIL total="7919.16">
    <GROUP desc="OSCAR_MURPHY" total="7919.16" acvTotal="8060.24" rcvTotal="8060.24" tax="141.08">
      <GROUPS>
        <GROUP desc="Main Level" total="7888.97" acvTotal="8030.05" rcvTotal="8030.05" tax="141.08">
          <ITEMS total="6394.83">
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="1" cat="FRM" sel="IJ9" act="&amp;" desc="I-joist - 9 1/2&quot; deep - 1 3/4&quot; flange" calc="164.67" qty="164.67" unit="LF" coverageName="Building" remove="0.76" replace="3.19" total="650.45" acv="650.45" recoverable="1" tax="19.27" acvTotal="669.72" rcvTotal="669.72" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="329.34" laborBase="144.91" laborBurden="85.63" laborMarkup="98.8" laborHours="8.42" material="321.11" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="0.76" acvTotal="0.76" rcvTotal="0.76" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="1.24" matUnit="1.95" tax="0.12" acvTotal="3.31" rcvTotal="3.31" trade="CARP-FRM" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="3" cat="FRM" sel="SHW3/4T" act="&amp;" desc="Sheathing - OSB - 3/4&quot; - tongue and groove" calc="192" qty="192" unit="SF" coverageName="Building" remove="0.91" replace="1.47" total="456.96" acv="456.96" recoverable="1" tax="8.29" acvTotal="465.25" rcvTotal="465.25" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="318.72" laborBase="140.16" laborBurden="80.64" laborMarkup="97.92" laborHours="8.46" material="138.24" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="0.91" acvTotal="0.91" rcvTotal="0.91" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="0.75" matUnit="0.72" tax="0.04" acvTotal="1.51" rcvTotal="1.51" trade="CARP-FRM" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="4" cat="FRM" sel="DBP6" act="&amp;" desc="Drilled bottom plate - 2&quot; x 6&quot; treated lumber" calc="50.67" qty="50.67" unit="LF" coverageName="Building" remove="3.57" replace="2.36" total="300.47" acv="300.47" recoverable="1" tax="3.1" acvTotal="303.57" rcvTotal="303.57" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="248.79" laborBase="107.42" laborBurden="62.32" laborMarkup="79.05" laborHours="6.88" material="51.68" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="3.57" acvTotal="3.57" rcvTotal="3.57" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="1.34" matUnit="1.02" tax="0.06" acvTotal="2.42" rcvTotal="2.42" trade="CARP-FRM" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="5" cat="CNC" sel="FTG-" act="&amp;" desc="Footings - labor and materials" calc="2.54" qty="2.54" unit="CY" coverageName="Building" remove="106.07" replace="270.31" total="956.01" acv="956.01" recoverable="1" tax="15.76" acvTotal="971.77" rcvTotal="971.77" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="626.82" laborBase="209.96" laborBurden="113.79" laborMarkup="303.07" laborHours="13.14" material="262.74" equipment="66.45" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="88.87" equUnit="17.2" acvTotal="106.07" rcvTotal="106.07" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="157.91" matUnit="103.44" equUnit="8.96" tax="6.21" acvTotal="276.52" rcvTotal="276.52" trade="CNC" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="7" cat="CNC" sel="RBJ42" act="+" desc="Steel rebar - j-bar - #4, 2' 6&quot;" calc="48" qty="48" unit="EA" coverageName="Building" replace="2.48" total="119.04" acv="119.04" recoverable="1" tax="2.48" acvTotal="121.52" rcvTotal="121.52" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="77.76" laborBase="22.08" laborBurden="11.52" laborMarkup="44.16" laborHours="1.25" material="41.28" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="1.62" matUnit="0.86" trade="CNC" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="8" cat="CNC" sel="RB4" act="&amp;" desc="Steel rebar - #4 (1/2&quot;)" calc="106.17" qty="106.17" unit="LF" coverageName="Building" remove="0.99" replace="0.92" total="202.79" acv="202.79" recoverable="1" tax="2.87" acvTotal="205.66" rcvTotal="205.66" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="155.01" laborBase="58.39" laborBurden="32.91" laborMarkup="63.71" laborHours="3.88" material="47.78" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="0.99" acvTotal="0.99" rcvTotal="0.99" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="0.47" matUnit="0.45" tax="0.03" acvTotal="0.95" rcvTotal="0.95" trade="CNC" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="9" cat="CNC" sel="FW-" act="&amp;" desc="Concrete wall - labor &amp; materials" calc="4.87" qty="4.87" unit="CY" coverageName="Building" remove="184.02" replace="235.54" total="2043.26" acv="2043.26" recoverable="1" tax="29.73" acvTotal="2072.99" rcvTotal="2072.99" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="1361.8" laborBase="493.33" laborBurden="272.38" laborMarkup="596.09" laborHours="32.04" material="495.57" equipment="185.89" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="154.23" equUnit="29.79" acvTotal="184.02" rcvTotal="184.02" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="125.4" matUnit="101.76" equUnit="8.38" tax="6.11" acvTotal="241.65" rcvTotal="241.65" trade="CNC" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="10" cat="CNC" sel="RB4" act="&amp;" desc="Steel rebar - #4 (1/2&quot;)" calc="872.17" qty="872.17" unit="LF" coverageName="Building" remove="0.99" replace="0.92" total="1665.85" acv="1665.85" recoverable="1" tax="23.55" acvTotal="1689.4" rcvTotal="1689.4" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="1273.37" laborBase="479.69" laborBurden="270.37" laborMarkup="523.31" laborHours="31.91" material="392.48" containsBSCDontApply="1">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="0.99" acvTotal="0.99" rcvTotal="0.99" trade="DMO" />
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="0.47" matUnit="0.45" tax="0.03" acvTotal="0.95" rcvTotal="0.95" trade="CNC" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
          </ITEMS>
          <GROUPS>
            <GROUP desc="Room1" total="1494.14" acvTotal="1530.17" rcvTotal="1530.17" tax="36.03">
              <ROOM_INFO sketchCeiling="8'" />
              <ROOM_DIM_VARS sfWalls="384" sfCeiling="144" sfWallsCeiling="528" sfFloor="144" syFloor="16" lfFloorPerim="48" lfCeilingPerim="48" />
              <ITEMS total="1494.14">
                <ITEM type="I" lineNum="15" cat="FCC" sel="AV" act="-" desc="Carpet" calc="F" qty="144" unit="SF" coverageName="Building" remove="0.19" total="27.36" acv="27.36" recoverable="1" acvTotal="27.36" rcvTotal="27.36" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="27.36" laborBase="11.52" laborBurden="7.2" laborMarkup="8.64" laborHours="0.78" containsBSCDontApply="1">
                  <ITEM_ACTS>
                    <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="0.19" trade="DMO" />
                  </ITEM_ACTS>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM type="I" lineNum="13" cat="FCC" sel="AV" act="+" desc="Carpet" calc="(F)*1.15" qty="165.6" unit="SF" coverageName="Building" replace="2.64" total="437.18" acv="437.18" recoverable="1" tax="21.46" acvTotal="458.64" rcvTotal="458.64" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="69.55" laborBase="29.81" laborBurden="14.9" laborMarkup="24.84" laborHours="1.6" material="357.7" equipment="9.93" containsBSCDontApply="1">
                  <ITEM_ACTS>
                    <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="0.42" matUnit="2.16" equUnit="0.06" trade="FLR" />
                  </ITEM_ACTS>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM type="N">
                  <NOTE>15 % waste added for Carpet.</NOTE>
                </ITEM>
                <ITEM type="I" lineNum="11" cat="DRY" sel="1/2++" act="&amp;" desc="1/2&quot; drywall - hung, taped, with smooth wall finish" calc="WC" qty="528" unit="SF" coverageName="Building" remove="0.28" replace="1.67" total="1029.6" acv="1029.6" recoverable="1" tax="14.57" acvTotal="1044.17" rcvTotal="1044.17" isPartOfInitSettle="1" laborTotal="786.72" laborBase="343.2" laborBurden="179.52" laborMarkup="264" laborHours="19.26" material="242.88" containsBSCDontApply="1">
                  <ITEM_ACTS>
                    <ITEM_ACT act="-" labUnit="0.28" acvTotal="0.28" rcvTotal="0.28" trade="DMO" />
                    <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="1.21" matUnit="0.46" tax="0.03" acvTotal="1.7" rcvTotal="1.7" trade="DRY" />
                  </ITEM_ACTS>
                </ITEM>
              </ITEMS>
            </GROUP>
          </GROUPS>
        </GROUP>
        <GROUP desc="Labor Minimums Applied" total="30.19" acvTotal="30.19" rcvTotal="30.19">
          <ITEMS total="30.19">
            <ITEM type="I" lineNum="14" cat="FCC" sel="MN-A" act="+" desc="Carpet labor minimum" calc="1" qty="1" unit="EA" coverageName="Building" replace="30.19" total="30.19" acv="30.19" recoverable="1" acvTotal="30.19" rcvTotal="30.19" isPartOfInitSettle="0" laborTotal="30.19" laborBase="30.19">
              <ITEM_ACTS>
                <ITEM_ACT act="+" labUnit="30.19" />
              </ITEM_ACTS>
            </ITEM>
          </ITEMS>
        </GROUP>
      </GROUPS>
      <AREA_DIM_VARS sfWalls="384" sfCeiling="144" sfWallsCeiling="528" sfFloor="144" syFloor="16" lfFloorPerim="48" lfCeilingPerim="48" sfSkFloor="144" sfSkTotalFloor="160.44" sfSkIntWall="384" sfSkExtWall="456" lfSkExtWallPerim="50.67" />
    </GROUP>
  </LINE_ITEM_DETAIL>
  <RECAP_BY_ROOM total="7919.16">
    <RECAP_GROUP desc="OSCAR_MURPHY" subtotal="7919.16" subtotalPercentage="100">
      <RECAP_GROUPS>
        <RECAP_GROUP desc="Main Level" items="6394.83" itemsPercentage="80.75" subtotal="7888.97" subtotalPercentage="99.62">
          <RECAP_GROUPS>
            <RECAP_GROUP desc="Room1" items="1494.14" itemsPercentage="18.87" />
          </RECAP_GROUPS>
        </RECAP_GROUP>
        <RECAP_GROUP desc="Labor Minimums Applied" items="30.19" itemsPercentage="0.38" />
      </RECAP_GROUPS>
    </RECAP_GROUP>
  </RECAP_BY_ROOM>
  <RECAP_BY_CATEGORY subtotalRCV="8060.24">
    <OP_ITEMS subtotalRCV="7919.16" subtotalPercentage="98.25">
      <CATEGORY desc="GENERAL DEMOLITION" rcv="2790.12" percentage="34.62" />
      <CATEGORY desc="CONCRETE &amp; ASPHALT" rcv="2852.79" percentage="35.39" />
      <CATEGORY desc="DRYWALL" rcv="881.76" percentage="10.94" />
      <CATEGORY desc="FLOOR COVERING - CARPET" rcv="467.37" percentage="5.8" />
      <CATEGORY desc="FRAMING &amp; ROUGH CARPENTRY" rcv="927.12" percentage="11.5" />
    </OP_ITEMS>
    <SALES_TAXES>
      <SALES_TAX desc="Material Sales Tax" percentage="1.75" rcv="141.08" />
    </SALES_TAXES>
  </RECAP_BY_CATEGORY>
</GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT>
```

Now i want to get some of the data from this XML , such as i need to have a query which can return me the following data

`dateCreated  =  2015-01-08T20:26:28

estimateName =  OSCAR_MURPHY

PHONE type   =  Business
ContactName  =  JohnDeeter`

Can someone please help me with a query to get these columns derived from XML ,i need all the columns from this XML but if someone can help me with a few i can use it and derive all.

Thanks in advance to everyone and please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please tag your question with the actual RDBMS (vendor and version), XML is highly product specific! And please reduce the given XML to a minium to show the principles. Further more it is highly appreciated to show some own effort. This tells us often more than your explanations :-)

Comment: Hi Shnugo, Thanks for the reply the reason i gave whole XML was because i found some google examples which are working fine with other XML i have used but this one seems a bit strange and its not working for example like  if i use the below query i hope to get the majorversion value which is in the first row of the XML but its not                          SELECT Value = X.XMLValue.value('(/GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT/majorVersion//node())[1]', 'int')  
FROM
    dbo.XMLData X

Comment: From your code in comment I assume this is SQL-Server. Tagged it accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML is by no means strange, just a bit more complex... And there is default namespace... Try this:

```
DECLARE @dummyXMLData TABLE(XMLValue XML);
INSERT INTO @dummyXMLData VALUES
(N'<GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT xmlns="http://xactware.com/generic_roughdraft.xsd" majorVersion="28" minorVersion="300" transactionId="001SPL8">
  <HEADER dateCreated="2015-01-08T20:26:28" />
  <COVERSHEET>
    <ESTIMATE_INFO estimateName="OSCAR_MURPHY" insuredName="Oscar Murphy" priceList="KYLO8X_JAN15" laborEff="Restoration/Service/Remodel" claimNumber="KBR-182015-13:18:46 MST" policyNumber="KBR1467216" typeOfLoss="Collapse" causeOfLoss="collapse" deprMat="1" deprNonMat="1" deprTaxes="1" recipientsXNAddress="XA.ONLINE.TEST" rotationTrade="Re Key\Lock Change" carrierId="2210000" estimateType="Structural" />
<!--Deleted for brevity-->    
  <PHONES>
      <PHONE type="Home" primary="1" phone="(800) 555-5765" />
      <PHONE type="Business" phone="(801) 555-2021" />
      <PHONE type="Cellular" phone="(808) 555-0202" />
    </PHONES>
    <CONTACTS>
      <CONTACT type="ClaimRep" name="John Deeter">
<!--Deleted for brevity-->    
      </CONTACT>
      <CONTACT type="Estimator" name="John Deeter">
<!--Deleted for brevity-->    
      </CONTACT>
    </CONTACTS>
    <DATES loss="2015-01-07" inspected="2015-01-08T05:00:00Z" completed="2015-01-08T20:26:26Z" received="2015-01-08T20:18:00Z" entered="2015-01-08T20:22:00Z" contacted="2015-01-08T05:00:00Z" />
  </COVERSHEET>
<!--Deleted for brevity-->    
</GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT>');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://xactware.com/generic_roughdraft.xsd')
SELECT X.XMLValue.value(N'(/GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT/HEADER/@dateCreated)[1]','datetime') AS DateCreated
      ,X.XMLValue.value(N'(/GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT/COVERSHEET/ESTIMATE_INFO/@estimateName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS EstimateName
      ,X.XMLValue.value(N'(/GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT/COVERSHEET/PHONES/PHONE[@type="Business"]/@phone)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS BusinessPhone
      ,X.XMLValue.query(N'/GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT/COVERSHEET/CONTACTS/CONTACT') AS AllConctacts 
FROM @dummyXMLData X
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked perfectly fine. However i have another scenario where the XML has data something like this                                          <ATT_FILE fileType="PDF" fileDate="2017-12-06T07:45:45" fileDesc="Activity Report" fileName="ACTIVITY REPORT.PDF"/>

<ATT_FILE fileType="PDF" fileDate="2017-12-06T07:44:01" fileDesc="Final Report" fileName="FINAL REPORT.PDF"/>                                  How do i seperate now these attachemnts to differentiate which is XML and which is PDF while loading?

Comment: @JohnBryan,Hi,I'm glad that this solved your problem! Please avoid *follow-up* questions. SO is living on *one issue- one question*. A new question will attract many readers. And please try to create a *stand-alone* test scenario (like mine above). This will get you the fastest and best response. Happy Coding!